# Do msal-angular package supports Authorization code flow using PKCE?

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal

I have registered two application on which represents a client while another represents a backend web api in azure active directory. Now I have an angular SPA where in I want to use MSAL angular library to support authorization code flow using PKCE to obtain a auth code and redeem that and get auth_token, id_token and refresh token. So is it possible? I am not very sure on how to go about with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MSAL.js with Angular

The current MSAL.js 2.x (msal-browser) implements auth code (w/ PKCE) flow. There is also an [MSAL-Angular wrapper library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular), which comes with some extra features and glue code, and that is the one that implements implicit flow (because it is based on MSAL.js 1.x aka msal-core). However, you don't have to use it just because you have an Angular project. Instead, you can create your own authentication service using MSAL.js 2.x directly.please refer to this similar question for [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63408467/how-to-implement-authorization-code-grant-with-pkce-in-angular6-applications#:%7E:text=x%20(msal-browser)%20implements,js%201)